# Is there any way to submit spark job using API

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, distributed-computing, spark-submit

I am able to submit spark job on linux server using console. But is there any API or some framework that can enable to submit spark job in linux server?

Comment: what is your resource/cluster manager ?

Comment: Spark jobs are running on linux clustered server

Comment: Are you using YARN or Spark standalone mode ?

Comment: I am using YARN

Answer (score 0):

You can use port 7077 to submit spark jobs in you spark cluster instead of using spark-submit.

```
val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.master(spark://master-machine:7077)
```

Comment: By writing this code spark job will submit in spark server?

Comment: Executing a program with that sentence, automatically, send a spark job to your cluster. Try it and let me know ;)

Comment: My question is how to submit spark job using API?

Comment: Javier your code will tell Spark to run as standalone on master-machine host will not submit anything

Answer (score 0):

you can look into Livy server. It is in GA mode in Hortonworks and Cloudera distros of Apache Hadoop. We have had good success with it. its documentation is good enough to get started with. Spark jobs start instantaneously when submitted via Livy since it has multiple SparkContexts running inside it.